# how to merge multiple text file as seperate sheets in excel with the name of the textfile as the name of the sheet using python

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, excel-2010, text-files

I am new to python and want to try to move multiple text file into single excel file.

I have around 10 textfiles containing data.

I want to read the text file and combine those in a single excel file with each sheet in excel containing complete data of each textfile and name of the textfile representing the excelsheet name using python.

This is what I tried to do:

```
import fileinput
import glob
import csv
import itertools
import time

def merge_text_files():
    file_list = glob.glob("*.txt")
    extra_line=("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")
    with open('result.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.writelines("\n")
    print file_list
    input_lines = fileinput.input(file_list)
    file.writelines(input_lines)
    return

def text_to_csv():
    with open('result.txt', 'r') as in_file:
    stripped = (line.strip() for line in in_file)
    lines = (line for line in stripped if line)
    grouped = itertools.izip(*[lines] * 3)
    with open('result.csv', 'w') as out_file:
    writer = csv.writer(out_file)
    #writer.writerow(('title', 'intro', 'tagline'))
    writer.writerows(grouped)
    return

def begin(val1,rep_file):
    try:
        print("merging of text files")
        merge_text_files()
        print("convert file to csv")
        text_to_csv()
    except:
        #print "exception occured in standby.begin()"
        return 1

def end(val1, rep_file):
    try:
        print "done"
        #display('ON')
        #wifi_disable()
    except:
        print "exception occured in end()"
        return 1

if __name__=="__main__":
    print "script to result"
    begin(1,"new")`enter code here`
    time.sleep(2)
    #begin(2,"new")
```

- text1.txt:

  ```
  No of scores is : 1
  Before Sorting 1 Scores : 330
  After Sorting 1 Scores : 330
  Median is : 330
  ```
- text2.txt:

  ```
  No of scores is : 1
  Before Sorting 1 Scores : 1744
  After Sorting 1 Scores : 1744
  Median is : 1744
  ```
- ...

Expected result should look like:

```
    No of scores is : 1
    Before Sorting 1 Scores : 330
    After Sorting 1 Scores : 330
    Median is : 330
```

1st sheet in excel named as `text1`

```
    No of scores is : 1
    Before Sorting 1 Scores : 1744
    After Sorting 1 Scores : 1744
    Median is : 1744
```

2nd sheet in excel named as `text2`

- ...

Comment: i am merging all text file and converting it to csv which looks too bad to the user to read this is wht i tried def merge_text_files():
        file_list = glob.glob("*.txt")
        extra_line=("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")
        with open('result.txt', 'w') as file:
                file.writelines("\n")
                print file_list
                input_lines = fileinput.input(file_list)
                file.writelines(input_lines)
                return

Comment: @SriharshaG provide the code sample in question edit it

Comment: you could use xlsx writer module to write into excel\

Comment: @SriharshaG provide sample of the input and the output you got and the expected output

Comment: i think you got the expected result.please reply me for more query

Comment: @SriharshaG: Do you want to have an Excel-file (xls) or a csv-file? As far as I know, csv-files do not support several datasheets or workbooks.

Comment: expected result is excel fle

Comment: If so, please adapt your question by editing it (question text and tags)

Comment: Edited the question and the explanation

Comment: @albert..is it possible to provide the code for this????

Comment: anyone able to help me in this task?????